# ms access database character encoding

Tags: database, ms-access

I have this really old access database, when i open it normally I do not get the correct text, only some gibberish, the only way to be able to read the contents is by doing export to text file, then opening that text file with encoding "Arabic (Windows-1256)"

How do i permanently fix that database (using access 2010) ?

How do I manage access databases character encoding ?

Comment: May be of interest: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-the-arabic-code-page-HP005257926.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it was to export each database table to text file, and then change the text file encoding, then import it again (in a new MySql database).

I couldn't find a more straight forward method of doing it, but it worked.